# Is Angular service private field secure?

Tags: angular, security, token

I'm kinda new to building secure web applications, especially ones built on JS.

I have this Angular based app I'm writing and I heard a lot of things about how an access token, for example, can easily leak through the local storage of a web browser.

I know, that I should avoid local storage and should use session storage instead, but I think there is something missing from the whole picture.

If I were to use an Angular service to do the authentication, could I use a private field in that service to store my token? Is there a way to leak the content of that service? What are the circumstances? *I come from Java, so my main assumption here is that accessing private fields is "hard"*.

What are some drawbacks I'm facing? Will the value stored in that private field persist after changing pages, or going to another site and then back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about not storing the token in localStorage. You must have found a lot of material about that already (otherwise, here is a good post: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/is-localstorage-a-security-liability-for-jwts).

Your question is different though. Keep in mind that `private` fields are just semantics that Typescript offers for the visibility of a variable at runtime.

It is just semantics to prevent your own code from directly accessing the variable from outside the class, **inside your code**, and breaking the architecture you want to enforce on your own code.

Any value that is used inside your code has its scope limited to the current execution of your app (typically as long as the tab is open), and its own scope in the Typescript code of course.

What you are talking about is persistence **between separate executions** of your app. So, the `private` setting of a variable has nothing to do with it being accessible from an attacker. It is rather a way for your code to avoid bugs, enforcing sound programming patterns.

Comment: and what about session storage? isn't is safe?

Comment: session storage is the same as local storage in theory, it just resets at every browser restart instead of every browser full cleaning. So it doesn't differ. See for example: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/is-localstorage-a-security-liability-for-jwts . The same applies for sessionStorage of course.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking. Don't store anything in the browser you don't want other users to see. Everything inside the browser is exposed and accessible to the person sitting at the computer.

Regarding the different types of storage, they are all "secure" within reason. This means that the internet browser does its best to prevent users from being malicious using set policies and restrictions for how these storage mediums are used. For example, storage access is usually scoped to the domain or page you are viewing, so another site isn't going to easily be able to access information that belongs to another domain.

In regards to session storage specifically, it is usually a better choice for tokens because once the page session is closed, the data is cleared. This means a another user cannot open the browser later and retrieve tokens belonging to someone else. I've posted the session storage docs to let the rest of the facts speak for themselves. All you have to do now is decide which one is more appropriate for what you are doing.

**Session Storage** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

**Local Storage** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage